# CAM::PDF font resource (Where?)

Tags: cam-pdf

All,

- Good News: Using CAM::PDF fillFormFields to complete a PDF Form.
- Bad News : Getting "Could not find resource /Helv while preparing form field".

I suspect the Win32 font /Helv is not know by CAM::PDF.

- Question: Where does CAM::PDF look for its font "resource"?